# What JavaScript or how to build this chart/graph?

Tags: javascript, charts, graph

I come across http://flyspy.com/miles/ and been impressed by their chart/graph (the 2 and 3 one, I don't know is this 2 consider chart/graph)
Does anyone know how to build it? Or did they use any JavaScript script to build it?

Answer (score 2):

marcgg might be right. You should also consider using a svg library to draw vector graphs, though.
Have a look at [Raphaël](http://raphaeljs.com/) / [gRaphaël](http://g.raphaeljs.com/).

Even though Raphaël is my favorite library, there are several others.

Answer (score 0):

The small ones (#3) must be using Sparkline: http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/

I'm not sure about #2, but you can get the same result using flot: http://code.google.com/p/flot/